# Highlighting Code syntax in <pre> tag?

Tags: jquery, html, syntax

Is there any syntax highlighter which can highlight the code inside the `<pre>`? I have been searching a lot on internet but most of the syntax highlighters require the code to be wrapped in `<pre><code>`.

My problem is that I can not alter the syntax and add `<code>` inside the `<pre>` or I can not define any class for the pre. So I am looking for some highlighter which can just automatically highlight code inside the `<pre>`. Is it possible with any syntax highlighter?

Comment: What are you using that prevents you from changing <pre>? to <pre><code>? maybe the better solution would be to fix That so that it works in a way that you can use whatever solution you want.

Comment: @KevinB I'm using the very old version of bbpress, it automatically converts the `[code]` tags to `<code>`, and `[pre]` tags to `<pre>`. I'm not very expert to modify the bbpress core files.

Comment: Well, it looks like it is template-driven, so you would just have to find the template (in the theme folder) that outputs the post content and at that point replace <code> with <pre><code>. (don't forget to also do it for the end tags, and for the preview post template.) **As a side note**, have you looked at this one? http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/configuration/). You can configure, which tag do you want to use as a sign for highlighting.